# conditional probability of a family

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Family A has 6 members of which 4 are males and 2 are females & family B has 5 members of both genders.(totally 5 memebers) (Assume it is equi-probable for a member of unknown gender to be a male or female).
2 members are selected randomly either from family A or family B. If both members are female then probability that they belong to family A is?

I can understand that we have to use Bayes theorem here but here there are several cases for family B. How to solve in such cases.

Comment: Family B has 5 members in total or 5 male and female each?

Comment: I preassumed that family B had 10 members but have sincere doubts. Could you make things more clear please?

Comment: @drhab while we wait for OP to clarify, on your answer that you deleted, your first presumption seems to have legitimacy the way "two members are randomly selected either from family A or family B" reads in the question. I was thinking the same. Definitely a question that is not well framed.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, let's wait and see. Actually I kind of hope that my interpretation is wrong. That would make it a more interesting question. If my interpretation is correct then I will undelete of course.

Comment: Family B totally has 5 members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the probability to be M of F is equal $P(M)=P(F)=\frac{1}{2}$ any elements of the 30 events of the sample space are equiprobable, thus  you have

$$P(F=k)=\frac{\binom{5}{k}}{\sum_{i=1}^{4}\binom{5}{i}=30}$$

$F=1,2,3,4$

Here is the sample space $\Omega$, for your help in understanding

[image]

Comment: Why does order of the genders within the family matter

Comment: @Equation_Charmer : just to count how many elementary events are with 1F, 2F. 3F and 4F

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be the events that both members were picked from Family A and both members picked were female, respectively. We can use Bayes' Rule to compute $P(E_1 \mid E_2)$ as follows:

$$P(E_1 \mid E_2) = \frac{P(E_1 \cap E_2)}{P(E_2)} = \frac{P(E_1)P(E_2 \mid E_1)}{P(E_2)} .$$

To compute $P(E_1)$, the probability that both members were picked from Family A, we must note that each subset of members is equally likely. The desired probability is $P(E_1) = {6\choose 2}/{11\choose 2} = \frac{3}{11}$  since there are ${6\choose 2}$ possible subsets of two people from Family A out of ${11\choose 2}$ total possible subsets of two people.

Now we will compute $P(E_2 \mid E_1)$, the probability that both members picked were female *given* that both came from Family A. The required probability is $P(E_2 \mid E_1) = \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15}$ since it is just the probability of picking the two females without replacement.

Finally, we must compute $P(E_2)$, the probability of both members picked being female. This is a little bit trickier. Let's introduce a new random variable $X$ which denotes the number of females in Family B. Clearly, $X \sim \text{Bin}(5, 0.5)$. Now we can easily compute the result by conditioning on $X$. For a fixed value of $X = x$, the required answer is ${2 + x\choose 2}/{11\choose 2}$ since there are $2 + x$ total females (and we can choose any two of them) whereas there are $11$ total people (and we can choose any two of them when we don't have the constraint). Therefore,

$$P(E_2) = \sum_{x= 0}^{5} P(E_2 \mid X = x)P(X= x) = \frac{1}{55 \cdot 2^{5}}\left[{5\choose 0}{2\choose 2} + {5\choose 1}{3\choose 2} + {5\choose 2}{4\choose 2} + {5\choose 3}{5\choose 2} + {5\choose 4}{6\choose 2} + {5\choose 5}{7\choose 2}\right] = \frac{17}{110}.$$

Now we can just plug in the values to get the final answer:

$$P(E_1 \mid E_2) = \frac{\frac{3}{11} \cdot \frac{1}{15}}{\frac{17}{110}} = \boxed{\frac{2}{17}}$$

Comment: I think OP means family B has $5$ members of unknown gender with equal probability of them being male or female. Also in your working, you are assuming that both of them are from family A to be true. That is not correct. The event that is given to be true is that both are female. We need to find probability whether they are from family A. Pls check.

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @MathLover I just updated my answer.

Comment: Yes this now seems right based on the presumption. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: But Answer given was 2/9

Answer (score 1):

I have a different solution.

Assuming that the family B is composed by 5 members total (with both gender present and any guy with probability 0.5 to be male or female, independently), the distribution of # of females in B Family is

$$B_{Female} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{5}{30},  & \text{if $F=1$} \\
\frac{10}{30},  & \text{if $F=2$} \\
\frac{10}{30},  & \text{if $F=3$} \\
\frac{5}{30},  & \text{if $F=4$}
\end{cases}$$

Thus the requested probabilty is

$$\mathbb{P}[A|FF]=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{2}[\frac{10}{30}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{10}{30}\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{4}+\frac{5}{30}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}]}=$$

...easy simplify $\frac{1}{60}$ in every addend...

$$=\frac{2}{2+[1+3+3]}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: Can u explain those 5/30, 10/30,5/30 terms